# Repeating CSS Icon Background with changeable icon and background colors

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a repeating pattern background, for example a repeating star, example on font-awesome: https://fontawesome.com/icons/star?f=classic&s=regular

But I can't seem to figure out a way to be able to control both the background-image svg color, and the color of the actual background. I'd like to be able to change them in the html using `style=color: blue; background-color: red;` This is the crudely drawn background using css I'm trying to achieve. [image: This is an example of the background I'm trying to achieve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this example may be it will help you.

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.bg{
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  border:2px solid #333;
  color:#00a2e8;
  /* background:url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-star" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M2.866 14.85c-.078.444.36.791.746.593l4.39-2.256 4.389 2.256c.386.198.824-.149.746-.592l-.83-4.73 3.522-3.356c.33-.314.16-.888-.282-.95l-4.898-.696L8.465.792a.513.513 0 0 0-.927 0L5.354 5.12l-4.898.696c-.441.062-.612.636-.283.95l3.523 3.356-.83 4.73zm4.905-2.767-3.686 1.894.694-3.957a.565.565 0 0 0-.163-.505L1.71 6.745l4.052-.576a.525.525 0 0 0 .393-.288L8 2.223l1.847 3.658a.525.525 0 0 0 .393.288l4.052.575-2.906 2.77a.565.565 0 0 0-.163.506l.694 3.957-3.686-1.894a.503.503 0 0 0-.461 0z"/></svg>'), red;
  */
  background:url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="%2300a2e8" class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z"/></svg>'), red;
  background-size:75px;
    background-repeat:space
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: This does look amazing, thank you! As a further question, is there a way that I would be able to change both, the star color, and the background color in the page HTML?

Comment: My Pleasure. please select my answer as useful if you found it useful thanks

Comment: @Erikas the background color is applied to the div, not the SVG, so you can change that the absolute normal way. The SVG path color you want be able to change from the outside though - that needs to be done "within" the SVG, which is embedded directly into the stylesheet using a Data URI here - the `fill="%2300a2e8"` part needs changing accordingly. Of course you could set that whole value as inline style directly on the div as well, it doesn't have to be in your external stylesheet.

Comment: Using `fill="currentColor"`(`currentColor` is a reserved color name, that takes the value of the `color` assigned to the element) or a CSS variable won't work here though - because SVGs can only be styled "from the outside", if they are _directly_ embedded into the HTML (the `<svg>...</svg>` _as_ tags in the HTML) - anything else, as `img`, `object`, or like here, as a background image, explicitly does not allow for that.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @CBroe , I appreciate the clear explanation, marking this as answered.